# Docker compose containers not reachable inside host containers(container inside container)

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have my pipeline running on hist container which launches containers using docker compose file .Earlier my containers were accessible to each other when running n virtual machine but now when i launched these inside host container they are  not reachable .What could be reason and any workaround Highly appreciate any help.

ERROR below:

test_broker:29092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'test_broker:29092': Name or service not known (after 11ms in state CONNECT)